# Pass object as parameter in function not working

Tags: php

This seems extremely easy but for the life of me can't figure out why this is not working.  I am trying to simply pass an object into a function but I get this error:

Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to write_query() must be an instance of   mysqli, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\CSP\login\login.php on line 28 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\CSP\php_scripts\login_script.php on line 40

These are my functions definitions:

```
function conn_database()
    {
        if (!empty($_POST['userid']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
        {
            $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'csp');

            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
            {
                echo 'Connection to database failed:'.mysqli_connect_error();
                exit();
            }
            return $conn;
        }

    }


function write_query($userid, $password, mysqli $conn)
    {
        $query = 'select * from authorized_users '
        ."where userid= '$userid'"
        ."and password_id='$password'";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        return $result;
    }
```

I am calling them like this:

```
$conn = conn_database();
$result = write_query($userid, $password, $conn);
```

I'm type hinting in the definition of the write_query() but from what I understand from the error, my third argument is not considered an instance of mysqli.  (I am aware I should be salting the password and all, I'm just trying to get this to work first).  Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: This line probably returns `false`: `if (!empty($_POST['userid']) && !empty($_POST['password']))`. Doing a `var_dump($_POST)` inside `get_connection` would help you debug the problem.

Comment: function conn_database() does probably return NULL. I can't see the point of the if-statements ($_POST...), doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld it seems OP logic is that he only wants to connect to the database when the user submits their login (`login.php`) credentials.

Comment: @Prisoner.. this is still bad. that code should not be coupled to a db connection what the heck does connecting to a database have to do with a some variables in a web post...???

Comment: @Zak I know that. Check my answer I made before my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third paramater is not an instance of mysqli. It is null. This is because your `get_connection` function is not returning anything.

Why are you checking for this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['userid']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
```

This means you code will only try and connect to the SQL server if you provide it with post data for `userid` and `password` only. If this is the behaviour you want, you should put the `if` statement outside the function, something like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['userid']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
  $conn = conn_database();
  $result = write_query($userid, $password, $conn);
}
```

although it seems that `userid` and `password` aren't set, regardless. Make sure to check the `name` attribute on your inputs and do a `var_dump($_POST)` to see whats being posted to your script.

Comment: My reasoning for the check was to make sure that the user at least attempted to fill in a user name and password before connecting to the database instead of wasting time/resources on an empty form, I just went at it the wrong way.  But your solution fixed it, thank you :)